# Copy files to another directory containing the same directory structure in bash

Tags: linux, bash, find, cp

I have the following directory structure:

```
dir1
+-- _class1
|   +-- _i
|   +-- _ii
|   +-- _iii
|   +-- _...
+-- _class2
|   +-- _i
|   +-- _ii
|   +-- _iii
|   +-- _...
+-- _class3
|   +-- _i
|   +-- _ii
|   +-- _iii
|   +-- _...
+-- _...
```

Each class contains the exact same directories, and the directories contain `png` files.

What I want to do is copy the contents from `dir1` to `dir2` such that `dir2` has the following format:

```
dir2
+-- _i
|
+-- _ii
|
+-- _iii
|
+-- _...
```

For example: `dir2/i/*.png` should contain all the files in `dir1/class1/i/*.png`, `dir1/class2/i/*.png`, `dir1/class3/i/*.png`, etc...

I have tried doing the following:

```
for dir in dir1/*/; do 
    cp -r dir1 dir2; 
done
```

But I get the following structure instead:

```
dir2
+-- _i
|
+-- _ii
|
+-- _iii
|
+-- _...
|
+-- _class2
|   +-- _i
|   +-- _ii
|   +-- _iii
|   +-- _...
+-- _class3
|   +-- _i
|   +-- _ii
|   +-- _iii
|   +-- _...
+-- _...
|   +-- _i
|   +-- _ii
|   +-- _iii
|   +-- _...
```

It seems to only work on the first directory and then it proceeds to create other directories instead of copying them into the already existing directory structure.

What's the best way to go about doing this in bash?

Comment: `for dir in dir1/*/*/; do cp -r "$dir" dir2; done` Note that this does not solve possible conflicts in case there are files with the same name in e.g. `dir1/_class1/_i` and `dir1/_class2/_i` or `dir2/_i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard needs another level to match the `i`, `ii`, etc. directories.

```
for dir in dir1/*/*/; do
    cp -R "$dir" dir2
done
```

Comment: To avoid copying files that might reside in a `_class*` directory, I suggest to append a trailing `/` to the pattern as in the question. --> `for dir in dir1/*/*/` ...

Comment: While this does work better than my current solution, it also includes files outside of the directories. I suspect those files are the duplicate files?

Comment: You're starting the copying from one level higher, so you're copying the intermediate directory that you want to skip.

Comment: Sorry, I needed to add a trailing `/` to just get directories.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! One thing to note is that dir2 needs to be created before running the scripts above. Otherwise, for some reason, I end up getting some files outside of the directories.

Comment: That's true. If the destination doesn't exist, it's created as the directory to rename the original directory to, instead of putting it inside.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```sh
cp -R dir1/*/*/ dir2/
```

I don't think you need to iterate the pattern with the shell. The `cp` command can do it.